# jQuery Global function and Javascript .id method

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have been trying to create a crossfade plugin with previous and next buttons from an already existing plugin: [jqueryfancytransition](http://workshop.rs/projects/jqfancytransitions/) .This is meant to be an exercise for me and after I manage to understand how it works I want to write my own for an website.I should mention that I am still very new to both Javascript and jQuery and that makes me sometimes waste alot of time on stuff that for others may seem very simple.One of these things simple things is the following:

I have noticed in the plugin that the author uses alot the method .id on the img's I can't find it in the jQuery API so I figure it's a native Javascript method so I tried looking in the w3schools reference for Javascript can't find it there either.At first I thought that this returns the id of the selected element  but to my surprise while trying to create a simple example it didn't:

```
<div id="slideshowHolder">
    <img src="nemo.jpg" alt="" id="ion"/>
    <img src="toystory.jpg" alt=""/>
    <img src="walle.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($('div').id);
});
```

This seems to return undefined in the console.So my question is what those this method return and where can I read about it?.

Another thing I wanted to ask is if in jQuery you create a global function like this:

```
$.globalFunction = function(){}
```

Update: I know that id is an html element and I can select it in jQuery by using $('div#slideshowHolder') or return it using the attr method but if id is just an html method then what does these piece of code mean

`img[el.id] = new Array();`

el is an img what those el.id return

Comment: a few things: w3schools is not the most reputable site to learn from, if you're trying to learn jQuery i would suggest the [jQuery site](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery)

Comment: But ... your code references a different string than that used in any of the HTML elements you posted.  Also, when looking something up by "id" value in jQuery, you have to prefix the string with "#", just like in CSS.

Comment: I know that it isn't but it sometimes a good reference to learn about new methods and .id isn't a jQuery method so it is not on there site.If it is I didn't find it

Comment: Sorry about the bad typo on the code I corrected it

Comment: jQuery objects don't have an `id` property. Why do you think it does? Or do you refer to `jQuery`/`$` in *"what those this method return"*? If so, have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: *I know that id is an html element*: Uhm what? | If you have a reference to a DOM element, which `el` appears to be, `el.id` contains the ID of that element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.id. I suggest to read some more about jQuery and DOM basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$('div')` returned an element (or many elements), they would be jQuery-wrapped elements, not plain DOM elements. Therefor they would not have an id property. If you want to get the id from a jQuery-wrapped element, you would use `$('div').attr('id');`.

To answer your final question, which I believe you are asking about adding to the jQuery prototype, there are many good articles for this. I would suggest reading over [helephant's site](http://helephant.com/2009/01/18/javascript-object-prototype/). The jQuery object (`jQuery` or, as it is usually aliased, `$`) is just like any other object, so you can extend it's prototype just like any other object.

To answer your newly edited final question:

`img[el.id] = new Array();`

This is searching for the property `id` on the object `el`, using that value to search for a property `el.id` on `img` using the bracket notation since `el.id` is dynamic. If it finds this property on the `img` object it will erase it and assign it a `new Array()` object. If it does not find the property on the `img` object, it will create a new property on the fly and assign it a `new Array()` object.

Comment: i corrected the $('idiv') typo sorry for that it should have been $('div') I am selecting the tagname not the id with these

Comment: @user1146440 no problem, i have removed that part of the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

id is an HTML attribute.

You can select it by jQuery in this way:

```
$('img#ion');
```

Or using .attr() to get the value.

[Reference here](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: ok I agree and that I already new then what those these piece of code mean img[el.id] = new Array(); el is an img

Comment: he just store the id in a variable. so var id = something. with el.id he get the id of the element. but as plugin maybe you have to see the class or constructor of it to attach it with point (el.id).